# matching and replacing text in a string while keeping non replaced text

Tags: c#, regex

I know how to use Regex.Split() and Regex.Replace(); but not how to keep certain data when replacing.

if I had the following lines of text in a String[] (Split after every ;)

"

```
using system;
using system.blab;
using system.blab.blabity;
```

"

how would I loop trough and replace all 'using' to '' but match the whole line 'using (.+;)' for example.
and end up with the following (but not just Regex.replace("using", "");)
"

```
<using> system;
<using> system.blab;
<using> system.blab.blabity;
```

"

Comment: Is the first code block the expected input and the second code block the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close. You should use a named group for every logical item you're trying to match. In this instance, you're trying to match everything that is not the string "using". You can then use the notation ${yourGroupName} to reference the match in the replacement string. I wrote a tool called [RegexPixie](http://www.regexpixie.com) that will show you live matching of your content as you type so you can see what works and what doesn't work.

```
//the named group has the name "everythingElse"
var regex = new Regex(@"using(?<everythingElse>[^\r\n]+)");
var content = new string [] { /* ... */ };

for(int i = 0; i < content[i]; i++)
{
     content[i] = regex.Replace(content[i], "${everythingElse}");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have the paranthesis after the "not-end-of-line" part?

Answer (score 3):

if str is your current string then

```
            string str = @"using system;
            using system.blab;
            using system.blab.blabity;";
            str = str.Replace("using ", "<using> ");
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer, the Regex answer is a tad harder to read, but has more to offer if you need it.

Comment: Thanks Davio.
KISS principle

Comment: Well of course it will also replace random text occurences of `"using"` at other places in the search string, but I don't know if that will be a problem in practice. A random expression like `int usingInt = 1` will be changed to `int <using>Int = 1`.

Comment: Yep.But it's look like some C# classes using statment exporter sort of thing he is doing

Comment: This is the simplest way of doing it but of course this is only a small chunk of data that I am sorting trough and would replace things that shouldn't be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

using parens in a Regex instructs the engine to store that value as a group. then when you call Replace, you can reference groups with $n, where n is the number of the group. I haven't tested this, but something like this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"^using( .+;)$", "$1");
```

[Read here for more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: This works but I didn't choose this as a answer because the one above is much viggity's is easier to read especially when you need to keep different things that are spaced out.

Answer (score 0):

This combines 2 of the answers. It wraps [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` around `using` to perform a *whole words only* search and then captures the regex in a back-reference `$1`

```
string str = @"using system;
using system.blab;
using system.blab.blabity;";

str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b(using)\b", "<$1>");
```